# Github Recovery

Tags: git, github, data-recovery

I was trying to recover a single file from an old commit in my git repository through the command line and I accidentally reverted the entire commit to my very first commit (this was made in December) and now I can't see any other git pushes?

Have I just lost all of my data or is there a way to restore it?

Comment: What about `git checkout <commit hast> <path/to/file>`?

Comment: Assuming you overwrote the history on your origin, there might still be a local copy of the repository somewhere with the latest code. Check your local branches too.

Comment: Are the previous commits still present(in `git log`)?

Comment: I did a ' git log ' and the most recent commit it shows me is the one I accidentally reverted to

Comment: Does `git log` contain commits where it was correct?

Comment: no, thats the part that worries me.

Comment: Did you do a `git push -f` (or `git push --force`)? How did you overwrite it?

Comment: `git reflog` might help if you overwrote your history...

Comment: git reflog shows all the commits/changes I've made today, is there a way I can re-download from one of the hashes locally?

Comment: Just do `git merge <hash>`?

Comment: I tried to merge an older hash and it told me it would overwrite some of my files so I moved the ones it would overwrite into a different folder and now it wont merge at all? It might be obvious by now that I have no clue what I'm doing with Git. I made a big mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [this site](http://de.gitready.com/advanced/2009/01/17/restoring-lost-commits.html) states, you can do the following:

- Execute `git reflog` and look for a commit that contains your file. Remember the commit hash.
- Checkout the file using `git checkout <commit hash> <path/to/file>` or merge the commit with your head (`git merge <commit>`).

See the docs for [git reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog), [git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) and [git merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) for details.

Comment: I figurd out why that wouldn't work on my previous attempt, I seem to have recovered a good portion of my files! Thank you so much.

Comment: You can also reset your repository to that point using `git reset --hard <hash>` but don't forget to make a backup before.